# Test fails because of differences in date formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

The test below compares two dates. The test fails because of differences in date format. How can I make this test work?

```
expiration = Time.zone.now - 50.days
# some lines to update @organization with a new expiration
assert_equal @organization.exp, expiration
# puts @organization.exp => Mon, 16 Nov 2015
# puts expiration => Mon, 16 Nov 2015 14:22:39 CET +01:00
```

Comment: `expiration = Date.today - 50.days` and then `assert_equal @organization.exp, expiration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Time#to_date` method, like

```
assert_equal @organization.exp, expiration.to_date
```

Comment: @Marty, Good, could you choice answer?

Comment: Yes, in a few minutes I can select the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`@organization.exp` seems to be a `Date`, but `expiration` is not:

```
expiration = Time.zone.now - 50.days
#=> Mon, 16 Nov 2015 14:36:06 CET +01:00

expiration.class
#=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

To get a time zone aware `Date` instance, you can use [`Date#current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-current) and alter it using [`DateAndTime::Calculations#days_ago`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-days_ago):

```
expiration = Date.current.days_ago(50)
#=> Mon, 16 Nov 2015

expiration.class
#=> Date
```